# How to Identify which control is violated in parsleyjs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parsley.js, parsley

I want to know which control is violated...

```
function validate()
{

    vldt = $('#frmInt').parsley().validate();   
    
    alert(" is Submitted : "+  vldt ); 

    if(vldt == false)
    {
        alert(" Violdated Control is : " + ? )
    }

}
```

A first alert box will display 'is Submitted : false',
but, how can we get why the form is violated and which control is violated...

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the [field:error event](https://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#events) or look for elements having the class **parsley-error**:

```js
$('#demo-form').parsley().on('field:error', function(e) {
    var attrName = this.$element.attr('name');
    var lblTxt = this.$element.siblings('label[for="' + attrName + '"]').text()
    console.log('Validation failed for: ', lblTxt);
});

$('#demo-form [type="submit"]').on('click', function (e) {
    vldt = $('#demo-form').parsley().validate();
    return vldt;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js"></script>


<form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate="">
    <label for="fullname">Full Name * :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" id="fullname" required="">

    <label for="email">Email * :</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" id="email" required="">


    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="validate">
</form>
```